# scaling and rotating imageview

Tags: java, android

I'm preparing somecompass activity. 
I have my rose of winds .png and I want to scale it on activity start and rotate after orientation changed.

The problem is that when i scale my image (onCreate only), after first (and only first) use of rotate method my view is resized one more time, and I have no idea why.

Let me post you my rotate and scale methods. rose is my ImageView instance (ImageView rose)

Please take a look and post any advices. Should I try different way to scale my ImageView ?

Thx for any help !

Rotate (looks like working fine)

```
public void rotateRose(float angle){

            angle = 360 - angle;
            Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
            rose.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
            pivX = rose.getDrawable().getBounds().width()/2;
            pivY = rose.getDrawable().getBounds().height()/2;
            matrix.preRotate((float) angle, pivX, pivY);
            rose.setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
```

Scale (found [source link](http://argillander.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/scale-image-into-imageview-then-resize-imageview-to-match-the-image/))

```
private void scaleImage(ImageView view, int boundBoxInDp)
    {
        // Get the ImageView and its bitmap
        Drawable drawing = view.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawing).getBitmap();

        // Get current dimensions
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();

        // Determine how much to scale: the dimension requiring less scaling is
        // closer to the its side. This way the image always stays inside your
        // bounding box AND either x/y axis touches it.
        float xScale = ((float) boundBoxInDp) / width;
        float yScale = ((float) boundBoxInDp) / height;
        float scale = (xScale <= yScale) ? xScale : yScale;

        // Create a matrix for the scaling and add the scaling data
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

        // Create a new bitmap and convert it to a format understood by the ImageView
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
        BitmapDrawable result = new BitmapDrawable(scaledBitmap);
        width = scaledBitmap.getWidth();
        height = scaledBitmap.getHeight();

        // Apply the scaled bitmap
        view.setImageDrawable(result);

        // Now change ImageView's dimensions to match the scaled image
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        params.height = height;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);

        //pivX = width/2;
       // pivY = height/2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i've got it !

replace

```
view.setImageDrawable(result);
```

in Scale method with

```
view.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
```

If you are looking for scaling and rotating methods for image view: These above works fine (with this little change )